# Storybook react-native check the render method of `CellRenderer`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, storybook, react-native-vector-icons

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `CellRenderer`.
>
> Error: Element type is
> invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a
> class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `CellRenderer`.
>
> ```
> at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (react-dom.development.js:23965)
> at createFiberFromElement (react-dom.development.js:23988)
> at createChild (react-dom.development.js:13628)
> at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:13900)
> at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:14305)
> at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:16762)
> at updateHostComponent (react-dom.development.js:17302)
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18627)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
> ```

I'm trying to use storybooks on a component that should work on react-native ios, android and web.

In this case on the Storybook we can try the web part, it seems to work, but the problem is when I put an icon, it gives me the problem listed above.

The insertion of an icon is done in the following way in obj in date:

`icon: (item, background) => Icon ({icon: 'user', item, background})`

Can you give me a hand?

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react-native'
import { withKnobs, object } from '@storybook/addon-knobs'
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard'

import { FontAwesome } from 'react-native-vector-icons'

const Icon = ({ icon, item, background }) => (
  <FontAwesome
    name={icon}
    size={40}
    color={item.iconColor || (!item.background || !background ? '#3498db' : '#fff')}
    style={item.styleIcon}
  />
)

const data = [
  {
    name: 'Me',
    background: '#3498db',
    icon: (item, background) => Icon({ icon: 'user', item, background }),
    iconColor: '#0d47a1',
    rippleColor: '#000',
  },
  {
    name: 'Family',
    background: '#b71c1c',
    //icon: (item, background) => Icon({ icon: 'gratipay', item, background }),
    styleIcon: { color: '#0d47a1' },
  },
  {
    name: 'Lovely',
    background: '#ffeb3b',
    //icon: (item, background) => Icon({ icon: 'heart', item, background }),
  },
  {
    name: 'Team',
    background: '#4caf50',
    //icon: (item, background) => Icon({ icon: 'users', item, background }),
    styleName: { color: '#0d47a1', fontWeight: 'bold' },
  },
  {
    name: 'Friends',
    nameColor: '#3498db',
    background: '#02cbef',
    //icon: (item, background) => Icon({ icon: 'group', item, background }),
  },
  {
    name: 'Calendars',
    background: '#ff5722',
    //icon: (item, background) => Icon({ icon: 'calendar', item, background }),
  },
]

const card = ({ name }) => console.log('Card: ' + name)

storiesOf('Dashboard', module)
  .addDecorator(withKnobs)
  .add('example', () => (
    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Dashboard data={data} background={true} card={card} column={2} rippleColor={'#3498db'} />
    </View>
  ))
```

Dashboard.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Platform, TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { FlatGrid } from 'react-native-super-grid'

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window')

const RippleColor = (...args) => (Platform.Version >= 21 ? TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple(...args) : null)

const Touchable = Platform.OS === 'web' ? TouchableOpacity : TouchableNativeFeedback

function Dashboard({ column = 2, data = [], card = () => {}, background, rippleColor = '#fff', ...props }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    widthDevice: width,
  })
  const { widthDevice } = state

  const onLayout = (e) => {
    const { width: widthDevice } = Dimensions.get('window')
    setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, widthDevice }))
  }
  var dim = widthDevice / column - 20
  return (
    <View onLayout={onLayout} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatGrid
        itemDimension={dim}
        data={data}
        style={styles.gridView}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <Touchable
            onPress={() => card(item)}
            delayPressIn={0}
            delayPressOut={0}
            useForeground={true}
            background={RippleColor(item.rippleColor || rippleColor)}
          >
            <View
              style={[
                styles.itemContainer,
                {
                  backgroundColor: !item.background || !background ? '#fff' : item.background,
                  height: dim,
                },
              ]}
            >
              {item?.icon && item?.icon(item, background)}
              <Text
                style={[
                  styles.itemName,
                  {
                    color: item.nameColor || (!item.background || !background ? '#000' : '#fff'),
                  },
                  item.styleName,
                ]}
              >
                {item.name || index}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </Touchable>
        )}
        {...props}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gridView: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  itemContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  itemName: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingTop: 10,
  },
})

export default Dashboard
```

Weback.config.js

```js
const path = require('path')
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  template: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/index.html'),
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body',
})

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'index.web.js'),
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
      '@storybook/react-native': '@storybook/react',
      'styled-components/native': 'styled-components',
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules[/\\](?!react-native-vector-icons)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            // Disable reading babel configuration
            babelrc: false,
            configFile: false,
            presets: [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              '@babel/preset-react',
              '@babel/preset-flow',
              '@babel/preset-typescript',
              {
                plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread'],
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules[/\\](?!react-native-super-grid)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            // Disable reading babel configuration
            babelrc: false,
            configFile: false,
            presets: [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              '@babel/preset-react',
              '@babel/preset-flow',
              '@babel/preset-typescript',
              {
                plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread'],
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        loader: 'url-loader', // or directly file-loader
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'),
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    hot: true,
  },
}
```

Comment: Is there error here in the story file or is it in `Dashboard` that is consuming the `data` prop? Is there a stacktrace to go with that error message?

Comment: @DrewReese: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but the problem only appears when something like this is used: `icon: (item, background) => Icon ({icon: 'user', item, background})` in the dashboard.js part it is named `{item?.icon && item?.icon(item, background)}`

Comment: I was just asking where the error is pointed to in your code. I suspect something somewhere in the `Dashboard` component is expecting valid JSX.

Comment: @DrewReese: I added the code for the dashboard and the webpack.config file.
Tell me if you want to know more information.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if there was a stacktrace for the error, to tell you exactly what line of code is the issue, and what was called up to that point.

Comment: @DrewReese: I changed the error message, see if that's what you said.

Comment: @DrewReese: From what I'm understanding it looks like a problem related to using
`react-native-vector-icons`
if instead of using this `import {FontAwesome} from 'react-native-vector-icons'` I use this `import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/dist/FontAwesome'` errors it doesn't give, but it doesn't show the same icon.
In your opinion what is the problem?